# Reading Attributes or Properties from Contracts

Tags: solidity, truffle

Let's say in an example i have a simple contract:

```
contract CryptoCharacters is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
  uint number;

  function setNumber(uint256 n) public { 
      number = n;
  }
}
```

To test this i wrote the following test:

```
  before(async function () {
        this.Chars = await ethers.getContractFactory("CryptoCharacters");
    });

    beforeEach(async function () {
        this._chars = await this.Chars.deploy()
        await this._chars.deployed()
        this.provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();
    });

 it('test setting number', async function () {
        await this._chars.setNumber.call(OWNER_ADDRESS, 123);
        number = await this._chars.number      
        expect(number ).to.equal(123);
    });
```

The main problem is that i have not found out a way to read the property `number` from the contrat without a getter function. Is there a way to read that property without a getter function ?

What if this property is another contract ? Could i read it like `myInstance.subcontract.property` ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

If you make the property `public`, it will be read-only available for other contracts and off-chain apps through an auto-generated getter function.

```
uint public number;
```

```
number = await this._chars.number()
```

---

Unless the property is `private`, child contracts can access it as read-write.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Parent {
    // read-only for external contracts and off-chain apps
    // read-write for child contracts
    uint public number;
}

contract Child is Parent {
    function foo() public {
        number++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this also work for child contracts ? Let's say i have an instance of a contract inside my contract. Would this also work ?

Comment: @GabrielSlomka Yes. Unless the property is `private`, child contracts can access it as read-write. I edited the answer and added an example. See the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters) for description.